# How I can make the legend of a plot, shows me each variable Im working on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, overlay, legend

Im making an overlay plot but when i add a legend and the legend shows in the graph it only shows one day that repeats several times like this

```
imagen = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))

for day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,26,27,28,30]:
    dia = datos[datos['Fecha'] == "2019-06-"+(f"{day:02d}")]
    tiempo= pd.to_datetime(dia['Hora'], format=' %H:%M:%S').dt.time
    temp= dia['TEMP']
    plt.plot(tiempo, temp) #, color = 'red' )# 

plt.xlabel("Tiempo (H:M:S)(Formato 24 Horas)")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura (K)")
plt.title("Temperatura Jun 2019")
plt.legend(datos['Fecha'])
plt.show()
imagen.savefig('TEMPJUN2019')
```

The image that i get from is the next one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ32T.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```py
imagen = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))

dia_lst = [] # <======================================================= Here
for day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,26,27,28,30]:
    dia = datos[datos['Fecha'] == "2019-06-"+(f"{day:02d}")]
    dia_lst.append(f"2019-06-{day:02d}") # <=========================== Here
    tiempo= pd.to_datetime(dia['Hora'], format=' %H:%M:%S').dt.time
    temp= dia['TEMP']
    plt.plot(tiempo, temp) #, color = 'red' )# 

plt.xlabel("Tiempo (H:M:S)(Formato 24 Horas)")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura (K)")
plt.title("Temperatura Jun 2019")
plt.legend(dia_lst) # <================================================ Here 
plt.show()
imagen.savefig('TEMPJUN2019')
```

So its seems that your datos['Fecha'] contain only one date, this is this one that you should update according to your need.

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly fine, thank you so much!!!!